# Truncated Bind on simple Coalesce

Tags: oracle

Changing nvl to coalesce should in theory be a drop in replacement function that provides the benefit of short circuit evaluation allowing the second parameter not to be evaluated.  This can be of benefit if the second (or later) parameter is a long running process.  We switched from NVL to COALESCE on a particular block of code and discovered we started getting ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value errors: Bulk Bind: Truncated Bind.  Here is the code:

```
BEGIN
   FOR vx IN (SELECT coalesce((SELECT to_char(10,'99') FROM dual), 'x') FROM dual) LOOP
      NULL;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

This has been reproduced on with sqlplus on 12g and 19g with a 19g client as well as using SQL Fiddle on 11.2 (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/afac2/1) and with Live SQL on 19.8 (https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/MP3Y2I9ZPBTMNWSV3XVWVYEF0).

The exception goes away if any of the following are done:

- 10 changed to 1.
- x changed to xx.
- Inner select replaced with hard coded value.

The SQL statement runs fine outside of a PL/SQL block.  It seems as if the

As an interesting comparison, this also gives an error:

```
DECLARE
   vx Varchar2(2);
BEGIN
   SELECT coalesce((SELECT to_char(10,'99') FROM dual), 'x') INTO vx FROM dual;
END;
/
```

But this is more expected because to_char(10,'99') returns the three character string ' 10'.  As expected, adding FM before 99 or increasing the Varchar2 to (3) resolves the issue.

If it were just an internal sizing problem then I wouldn't expect it to resolve itself by increasing the size of the second item in the coalesce, unless it were evaluating it for size somehow without evaluating it for results.

Is this a bug or is expected behavior?

Comment: I've done a trace per Doc ID 139548.1, but that didn't help answer the question.

Comment: That's a bug imo. In particular, dropping plsql optimization level to 1 still brings the error, which means its not an array fetch issue per se.